# Node Connect Static set Content-type text/plain not working

Tags: node.js, static, connect

I am trying to set the content type of the files served by connect.static to `text/plain`. I thought this would work, but connect seems to still be detecting the content type fomr the extension with the `mime` module.

```
var connect = require("connect")

connect()
    .use(connect.static(__dirname + "/public"))
    .use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    })
    .listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Is there any easy way of doing this? Maybe screwing around in connects instance of mime before it can get to it? Or will I have to rewrite connects static middleware?

Comment: Appreciate if you can provide the reason on why you want to overwrite the content-type . Static middleware handles all the recognized extenstion

Comment: I am creating a [simple static file server](https://github.com/giodamelio/takeapeek) in one command. Sometime I would rather view some file in the browser that are text but don't have a mime type as part of the `mime` module(coffee file). I am adding an option to do so.

Comment: @giodamelio If you want to add additional file types, so they're treated as `text` rather than [`application/octet-stream`](https://github.com/broofa/node-mime#mimedefault_type), you can use [`connect.static.mime.define()`](https://github.com/broofa/node-mime#api---defining-custom-types).

Comment: Yep, I know, but I wanted a catch all.

Comment: @giodamelio A "*catch all*" with `text/plain` includes any binary files you have, like images, that *shouldn't* be treated as `text`. If your site's contents consist entirely of text files of varying formats, then sure. But, that's rarely the case anymore.

Comment: In a normal use case sure, but this code is for a [simple static file server](https://github.com/giodamelio/takeapeek) in one command. It is meant for devs who know what they are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control of the filenames within the public directory, the easiest approach is to ensure that they end in '.txt', so that the mime map provides the send function with the correct Content-Type.

Failing that, you could change the default mime type:

```
var connect = require("connect")

var mime = connect.static.mime;
mime.default_type = mime.lookup('text');

connect()
    .use(connect.static(__dirname + "/public"))
    .listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Alternatively, if you really want every file served as text/plain, just set the Content-Type header before the static middleware is invoked. It only adds the header if it isn't already present on the response:

```
var connect = require("connect")

connect()
    .use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        next();
    })
    .use(connect.static(__dirname + "/public"))
    .listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only if the static middleware is not able to handle the request ,then the next middleware is executed.

Incase static middleware finds the file , it serves it to the client.Next middleware  is not executed.

That is the reason why your middleware is not effective.